# Got an error 1120 ~ Access of undefined property

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, timer

This is not your typical 1120. I know better than to have buttons/MCs without instance names on the timeline.

Nope, this problem resides in a I timer I built from script I found online. The undefined property is related to the timer class delay I want to implement.

What I'm trying to achieve is have the user click the next button, wait 1 sec., then scroll through the next content. I have the code sitting inside a conditional statement to reduce the amount of code.

One thing to note, I am using TweenLite for the transitions, if that makes any difference

Now, the following code will show you the timer only working work one next position. I want to eventually add this to the remaining next position and all the previous positions so that there will be a slight delay when scrolling through the content.

Also, I want to reuse the same code so when the user reaches a particular position, there will be a slight delay and load, and/or, make an image or text visible.

How would I solve my initial problem and then simplify the code to reuse the code throughout the project?

Thanks for the help in advance!

```
import gs.TweenLite;
import gs.easing.*;

var timer:Timer = new Timer(1500, 1);

next_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, nextListener);
prev_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, prevListener);
timer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, delay); //I get the error here with "delay" 

prev_mc.visible = false;

function nextListener(event:MouseEvent):void {

 if (this.content_mc.slider_mc.x == 0) {

  function delay(event:TimerEvent):void {
   TweenLite.to(this.content_mc.slider_mc, 1, {x:-923.2, y:0, ease:Quart.easeInOut});
   prev_mc.visible = true;
  }
 } else {
  TweenLite.to(this.content_mc.slider_mc, 1, {x:-1872, y:0, ease:Quart.easeInOut});
  next_mc.visible = false;
 }
}

function prevListener(event:MouseEvent):void {
 if (this.content_mc.slider_mc.x == -1872) {
  TweenLite.to(this.content_mc.slider_mc, 1, {x:-923.2, y:0, ease:Quart.easeInOut});
  next_mc.visible = true;
 } else {
  TweenLite.to(this.content_mc.slider_mc, 1, {x:0, y:0, ease:Quart.easeInOut});
  prev_mc.visible = false;
 }
}

next_mc.buttonMode = true;
prev_mc.buttonMode = true;

timer.start();
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the "delay" function is defined within your nextListener function, so it is not accessible in your `timer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, delay);` code.  I think you meant to move the `timer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, delay)` inside of the next button handler.

Answer (score 0):

This is a scoping issue. You are calling the 'delay' function from this line:

```
timer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, delay); //I get the error here with "delay"
```

but the delay function is defined in another function, *nextListener*.

That means that this line cannot see the delay function. To fix this issue, just put this line inside the nextListener function:

```
function nextListener(event:MouseEvent):void {
// newly added ---v
timer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, delay); //I get the error here with "delay" 
// rest of code
}
```